# Weight and size capacity for pedal cars

Tags: weight, size

Hi i recently became interested in pedal cars and i know this says its a bike website but was hoping someone could help me figure out the weight and height capacity of one cause i cant find any info anywhere and this website always popped up first when i tried and since they are kinda similiar i would hope someone could help. I looked for a while online and cant find anything on thos paeticular bit unfortunetly

Comment: It would depend completely on your legal jurisdiction.   My country has a maximum width and a maximum length for a bicycle, but no stated limits on weight (or height)   At some point, the end weight will be a result of other design choices, like number of riders.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's unlimited (other than by traffic laws).
[image]

Comment: The annual Hicks family outing there ;)